# c or objective-c equivalent of Java's Integer.toHexString()?

Tags: java, objective-c, c

Is there is an equivalent in C or Objective-C to do the following (taken from Java)

```
Integer.toHexString(some_int)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 32 bit Integers:

```
char buffer[enough_space_for_the_largest_string..];
sprintf (buffer, "%08x", YourNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", yourNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itoa()` with a base of 16 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: No such beast on OS X. Use `sprintf` or `NSString` formatters.

Answer (score 0):

The printf format specifiers %x and %X allow you to print an integer's hex representation. The same can be used with [NSString stringWithFormat:...] to get an Objective-C string.